# VisualSVN doesn't create the default folders

Tags: svn, visualsvn

After create a SVN repository using VisualSVN, I cannot see the default structure  (branches, tags e trunk) through Windows Explorer... I've checked "create default structure" checkbox...

It is correct? Should I create these folders "manually"?

How can I set it to automatically create these folders to me?

Answer (score 0):

We have always made the "branch", "trunk" and "tags" folders manually.

Comment: Because it's a VS plugin - AWK is nice because it's free.